# mysql date compare

Tags: mysql

In one of my mysql tables I have columns `start` `stop`. 
For example the value of start is `2011-01-21` and the value of stop is `2011-03-23`.
Assuming today is `2011-03-10` how to determine that "today" is between start and stop period ?

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from mytable where CURDATE() between start and stop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    *
from
   `tbl`
where
   now() between `the_start_date` and `the_end_date`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm bit ambiguous but you could store today date in a variable and do a "select start, stop from table" then in a PHP for loop you could evaluate whether your today variable is between the two date values?